# Extrapolate survival probabilities after a certain time

Tags: python, excel, survival-analysis, probability-distribution, hazard

I have hazard rates for different time periods and I estimated survival probabilities for different time periods. I would like to estimate survival probabilities for future time periods.

Here is the table I created on excel hazard rates & survival probabilities:

[image: data]

For survival probability in year 1, I used the following formula

> Q(1) = exp(-h(1)*dt), dt = 1
>
> where h(1) is hazard rate between year 0 and year 1
>
> Q(2) = Q(1)*exp(-h(2)*dt)), dt = 1,
>
> where h(2) is hazard rate between year 1 and year 2

How do I estimate survival probabilities for future years where I dont have hazard rates for future years?

Any help would be appreciated - even if its in python/R/excel. Thanks in advance

Comment: Except for the first point, this is pretty much linear.  You could assume 0.25% and not be far off.  What else can you do?